# How to launch a Google Chrome Tab with specific URL using C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, url, tabs

Is there a way I can launch a tab (not a new Window) in **Google Chrome** with a specific URL loaded into it from a custom app? My application is coded in **C# (.NET 4 Full)**.

I'm performing some actions via SOAP from C# and once successfully completed, I want the user to be presented with the end results via the browser.

This whole setup is for our internal network and not for public consumption - hence, I can afford to target a specific browser only. I am targetting **Chrome only**, for various reasons.

Answer (score 69):

As a simplification to [chrfin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472434/chrfin) response, since Chrome should be on the run path if installed, you could just call:

```
Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http://www.YourUrl.com");
```

This seem to work as expected for me, opening a new tab if Chrome is already open.

Comment: Apologies, I've just used the wrong terminology but it does work.
Just checked and it isn't on the PATH, it is definitely on the run path (whatever that actually uses) though - if you bring up the 'Run' prompt and run `chrome.exe "http:\\www.YourUrl.com"` it appears to behave the same way as C#.

Comment: Is there a way to know whether Chrome finished loading this URL (no longer busy), programatically, using C# as well? Something like [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/scriptcenter/en-US/70e63239-7c97-4176-a060-b95676deb4fe/vb-script-to-detect-a-webpage-is-loaded-or-not), but not with VBA but with C#.

Comment: How to open the YourURL page in background tab instead of current tab?

Answer (score 48):

```
// open in default browser
Process.Start("http://www.stackoverflow.net");

// open in Internet Explorer
Process.Start("iexplore", @"http://www.stackoverflow.net/");

// open in Firefox
Process.Start("firefox", @"http://www.stackoverflow.net/");

// open in Google Chrome
Process.Start("chrome", @"http://www.stackoverflow.net/");
```

For .Net core 3.0 I had to use

```
 Process process = new Process();
 process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
 process.StartInfo.FileName = "chrome";
 process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"http://www.stackoverflow.net/"; 
 process.Start();
```

Comment: For me it did't worked with .NET Core 3.0 in winforms application. Instead I have to use 
`Process process = new Process();`
`process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;`
`process.StartInfo.FileName = "chrome";`
`process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"http://www.stackoverflow.net/";`
`process.Start();`

Comment: Edge is a bit different also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39626953/685404

Comment: how it works with .Net 6.0 in debug mode it is working fine but when hosted as a service it's not throwing exception also not have any error so any idea?

Answer (score 25):

**UPDATE:** Please see Dylan's or d.c's anwer for a little easier (and more stable) solution, which does not rely on Chrome beeing installed in `LocalAppData`!

---

Even if I agree with Daniel Hilgarth to open a new tab in chrome you just need to execute chrome.exe with your URL as the argument:

```
Process.Start(@"%AppData%\..\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", 
              "http:\\www.YourUrl.com");
```

Comment: Question: Does this guarantee than an existing instance of Chrome will be used if one is already executing, and (if so) that the page will be opened in a new tab in lieu of a new window?

Comment: I can't guarantee it (may search the Chome settings for such a setting), but I tested it and it used the existing Chrome instance...

Comment: Please refer to the question to see why Chrome and why not other browsers.

@Mike Hofer: Yep. It's pretty much guaranteed that Chrome is present on all the systems, especially for those users who use SugarCRM.

@chrfin: Thanks! Let me give it a shot and get back to you.

Comment: Please be aware that Google Chrome is not always installed in the path stated above.

Comment: You can also use '%localappdata%' instead of jumping up from Roaming for windows 7 and 8 (possibly newer)

Comment: I've got mine under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application`

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http:\\www.YourUrl.com"); worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

If the user doesn't have Chrome, it will throw an exception like this:

```
    //chrome.exe http://xxx.xxx.xxx --incognito
    //chrome.exe http://xxx.xxx.xxx -incognito
    //chrome.exe --incognito http://xxx.xxx.xxx
    //chrome.exe -incognito http://xxx.xxx.xxx
    private static void Chrome(string link)
    {
        string url = "";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link)) //if empty just run the browser
        {
            if (link.Contains('.')) //check if it's an url or a google search
            {
                url = link;
            }
            else
            {
                url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + link.Replace(" ", "+");
            }
        }

        try
        {
            Process.Start("chrome.exe", url + " --incognito");
        }
        catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to find Google Chrome...",
                "chrome.exe not found!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```