# How to launch MS Edge from c# winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The executable MicrosoftEdge.exe cannot be launched directly like other EXEs in windows. I confirmed that from my own experience, and by reading [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_internet-insider_spartan/i-cant-start-microsoft-edge-by-opening-it-in/c3a28f76-7ec2-44ac-8586-5e7a58251292) and [that](https://superuser.com/questions/950435/where-is-microsoft-edge-located-in-windows-10-how-do-i-launch-it/950457).

I also cannot launch it via `Process.Start("MicrosoftEdge.exe")` in my c# winforms app.

There must be some way to launch Edge from winforms without resorting to 3rd-party app and other clutter. I have already tried the following, with no success:

1. `Process.Start("MicrosoftEdge.exe")` - unhandled exception
2. `Process.Start("microsoft-edge")`   - unhandled exception
3. `Process.Start("%windir%\explorer.exe shell:Appsfolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge")` - unhandled exception
4. `Process.Start(@"c:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe")` - no exception, but nothing happens

Note: I can easily launch Chrome and Firefox using method #1 above.

How can I launch MS Edge from my .net winforms app?

Comment: Check [this link](https://aruntalkstech.wordpress.com/2015/08/12/launch-a-universal-app-from-a-wpf-app/); it has a WPF sample but the codebehind should work too for winforms

Comment: @SweatCoder Have you tried the suggestions here [How to open URL in Microsoft Edge from the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164253/how-to-open-url-in-microsoft-edge-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Try number 3 with both a fielname and a Arguments parameter.

Comment: `Process.Start("msedge.exe")` Works for me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The ":" at the end is inportant, otherwise won't work

To open in blank:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("microsoft-edge:");
```

or specifying an address:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: This works as well: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("microsoft-edge:.exe");`

Comment: This only works for http urls and not for file:// urls.

Comment: Why oh why did ms have to do edge differently (to even ie and everything else): https://stackoverflow.com/a/14913755/685404

Answer (score 5):

Process.Start can take 2 parameters

```
string url = "http://www.google.com";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("msedge.exe", url);
```

Browsers:

- msedge.exe
- chrome.exe
- firefox.exe
- iexplore.exe

Answer (score 2):

You can use a small workaround to open Microsoft Edge from CMD with this code

```
string url = "https://www.google.com";

// Starts Microsoft Edge with the provided URL; NOTE: /C to terminate CMD after the command runs
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", $"/C start msedge {url}");
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are both valid, but there's one small issue I ran into when trying to use the option listed by @user1845593. It didn't work unless I used the `ProcessStartInfo` class and set `UseShellExecute` to `true`.

I was executing this with .net 6 and the below sample works for me. If I attempt to pass the same thing straight to `Process.Start` it fails.

```cs
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("microsoft-edge:");
processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(processInfo);
```