# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: "The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: c#, .net

Me again. I have an issue in Visual Studio 2017 where when I execute this code

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyCoreApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void openEdgeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start("start microsoft-edge:");
    }
}
```

}

It throws the error described in the question. The Program I want to execute is Microsoft Edge, and if I launch the Command Prompt and do it manually, it works without complaint. I have researched this problem elsewhere, and some people say it's to do with WOW or WOW64. But I'm new to Visual Studio, and am more familiar with Linux internals than Windows internals. Thank you for any help guys, and thank you SO much for your kindness and understanding.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626509/how-to-launch-ms-edge-from-c-sharp-winforms

Comment: Ah yes, Mary. Your Search-Fu is stronger than mine indeed! :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use it without start parameter

```
Process.Start("microsoft-edge:");
```