# Visual Studio 2019 Open URL In Browser Using VB

Tags: vb.net, url, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to use a LinkLabel to direct users of my program to my Discord server (so they can report bugs and whatnot), but every time I click on it I get an error saying 'The system cannot find the file specified.'

I was using `Process.Start("INVITE LINK")` as that was the code I found in the vast majority of results I got when I Googled the issue. However, it would seem that this doesn't work in Visual Studio 2019, as evidenced by the error I get. Either that, or I've overlooked something (which wouldn't be the first time, as I kind of have a habit of not reading things properly).

I'm sure I've managed it before, but I can't for the life of me remember how it was done; I'm asking here in the hope that someone can push me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you get? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4580317/832052) should just work.

Comment: 'The system cannot find the file specified.'

Comment: That answer you linked me to didn't work; it's for C# and I'm using Visual Basic.

Comment: In Windows go to Predefined Programs and check if the (predefined) Browser is correct. If it's correct then it's something wrong in your "INVITE LINK", should start with http://yourSite, maybe you are trying to open some local file like "C:\somethingThatDoesntExist.html"

Comment: The link starts with `https://discord.gg/(invite code goes here)`. The predefined (I assume that means default) browser is Firefox.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626509/how-to-launch-ms-edge-from-c-sharp-winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from an [answer in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580263/how-to-open-in-default-browser-in-c-sharp/4580317#4580317),

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
```

```cs
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true; 
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "https://discord.gg/(invite code goes here)";
myProcess.Start();
```

It's not much different in vb

```vb
Imports System.Diagnostics
```

```vb
Dim myProcess = New Process()
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "https://discord.gg/(invite code goes here)"
myProcess.Start()
```