# Trying to use the "launch url on c#" but doesnt work

Tags: c#

read title

Here is the code i'm using

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("My url, dont wanna show it xd");`

But visual studio tells this

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAKN6.png)

i tried using the light, but tells
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDmgi.png)

Comment: You probably want something like `_16.Click += delegate { Process.Start... };`

Comment: Please include any errors as _text_ in your question. Please also include a [mcve] in your question _as text_.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a method to the click event before you can call the Process.Start. For instance:

```
button14.Click += Button14_Click;
```

Now if you click the button it will open the browser.

```
 private void Button14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("my url");
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

Process.Start("chrome.exe", "http://www.YourUrl.com");

Similar question here: [How to launch a Google Chrome Tab with specific URL using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305388/how-to-launch-a-google-chrome-tab-with-specific-url-using-c-sharp)

Comment: This doesn't address why OP's code won't compile (considering `string filename` is an overload of [`Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_)).